# How to check whether the given function is continuous at (0,0)?

Tags: continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by f(0,0)=0 and f(x,y)=$\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}$ if $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$

Is $f$ continuous at $(0,0)$?

$\vert\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}\vert=\vert{y}\vert \vert\frac{x^2}{x^4+y^2}\vert \le\vert{y}\vert$ which tends to 0 as y$\to0$

Hence, by the sandwich theorem given function is continuous at (0,0).

Also along all the paths I am getting a limit of zero.

Please tell me any mistake.

Comment: got it . limit is dependent on path hence not continuous

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explain why continuity along straight lines is not enough to conclude continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1410889/explain-why-continuity-along-straight-lines-is-not-enough-to-conclude-continuity)

Answer (score 1):

Make the substitution $u=x^2$.

Now, you have $f(u,y)=\displaystyle \frac{uy}{u^2+y^2}$.

Converting to polar coordinates, $\displaystyle f(u,y)=f(r,\theta)=\frac{(r\cos(\theta))(r\sin(\theta))}{(r\sin(\theta))^2+(r\cos(\theta))^2}=\frac{r^2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{r^2}=\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\theta)$.

What does this even mean, you may ask?

Well, $\displaystyle \lim_{r \to 0}\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\theta)$ does not depend on $r$, and depends on $\theta$.

What does that mean? That means $f(r,\theta)=f(u,y)=f(x^2,y)$ approaches different values from different directions.

Therefore, the limit of $f(x,y)$ at $(0,0)$ does not exist.

---

Notice that the substitutions we made morph the function, but preserve the limit's properties.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the limit along the path $(x,y)=(t,t^2)$ as $t\to0$.